# Cannot add background to css class

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

i have this css class

```
.site-title .logoimage {
    background: url(~/Images/orderedList0.png)  center right; 
    color:red;
    display: block; 
    height: 84px; 
    width: 264px;
}
```

it is working and the prove is the `color red`, if i change it to green, the test becomes green and so on.
but i can't add the background of the image, i dont konw why.

the image is in the `Images` folder.

Comment: Check the URL from your file. ttry using ../../Images/orderedList0.png let me know if it works

Comment: @DawoodAwan all the problem in my opinion in the url, so what is the `....` that you wrote please?

Comment: try going to the root folder using ../../Images/orderedList0.pn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/Images/orderedList0.png` is not a valid URL. the tilde `~` is an Asp.Net construct that represents the site "root". It is not a concept which is "understandable" by your browser when parsing the CSS.

Try `/Images/orderedList0.png`

Comment: you are the one buddy, it works, i will accept you answer after 7 minutes

Comment: This is absolutely it. Theres a whole bunch of people out there who have "grown up" on the tilde syntax because of ASP.NET

Comment: @DarkoZ that is why i hate asp and i hate microsoft and i hate visual studio, but i HAVE to work with these ... :X

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli easy on the hate, the tilde is a good idea, but it trips up people familiar with APS.NET but new to CSS/HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL in `background: url(~/Images/orderedList0.png)  center right;`

Comment: that is the exact url that i am using, please check the question, i wrote it

Comment: there is a guy who downvote to your answer, but i upvote to your , thank you